# Is there something wrong with brackets? $f(2x+(f(y)+f(f(y))=4x+8y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving

> $ x,y \in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, find a function that,
>
> $$f(2x+(f(y)+f(f(y))=4x+8y$$
>
> A) $f(x)=2^x$
>
> B) $f(x)=2x$
>
> C) $f(x)=2^x-3$
>
> D) $f(x)=2x^2-3$
>
> E) $f(x)=4x-2$

My problem is,it seems to me that there's something wrong with brackets. Or do I think wrong?

Comment: Yes: the number of left ones does not match the number of right ones. But it is enough to add the two missing right parentheses.

Comment: I think two more parentheses should be added

Comment: It's not unamibiguous, though, is it @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Doing what you say, are you sure that question can be fixed only in one version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the red parenthesis is superfluous: $$f(2x+\color{red}{(}f(y)+f(f(y))=4x+8y$$
since $$f(y)+f(f(y)) = \color{red}{(}f(y)\color{red}{)}+f(f(y)) = \color{red}{(}f(y)+f(f(y))\color{red}{)},$$
so let us just ignore it.

That leaves us with three cases:

1. $f(2x\color{blue}{)}+f(y)+f(f(y))=4x+8y$
2. $f(2x+f(y)\color{blue}{)}+f(f(y))=4x+8y$
3. $f(2x+f(y)+f(f(y))\color{blue}{)}=4x+8y$

I believe the correct one should be 2., since it's the only one that one of the proposed solutions works for.

Comment: (+1) By the way thank you for not saying the answer. I'll solve it myself according to your correction.

Comment: @Beginner, you are welcome. If you are doing this for practice, I would still try the other two options as well. It might help you see why some of the proposed solutions cannot work, no matter the parentheses.

Comment: +1. Perfectly well explained.